# How to use this formula in Reports?

Tags: reporting, formula

I want to display a Case Created Hour,So I've a formula.I want to use this formula in Report.

VALUE(MID(TEXT(  CreatedDate  ),12,2)) + ( DST_Offset__c )

Here DST_Offset__c and CreatedDate are 2-fields.

Can we use this formula in Report formula filed?

Comment: did you tried that in you ORG? are you facing any issue?

Comment: I tried in my ORG,but unable to write this formula under Report --Add Formula.Only showing Summary,Larget,Smallest and Average.

Comment: you can not add this type of formula in reports https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IySFAA0 one option is create new formula field on Case object and then use it in report.

Answer (score 2):

The formulas in reports are different to the formulas we use in fields and criteria evaluation in Salesforce. You cannot write arbitrary formulas from within a report.

Your best option, as @AtulRajguru9 said, is to create this as a custom formula field in Case and then (having refreshed the page at least) add it to your report.

[image: fields]

then

[image: new]

and

finally

then

[image: formula]

you will now find the field available in reports

[image: report]

Comment: I've another query,Can we create this Report using VF and Apex.I mean without creating a new field on Object.

Comment: You can do anything with Apex and VF! However.. creating and displaying a whole report could be very time consuming indeed. A visualforce page with a custom controller, some page block tables and maybe some Apex Charting (https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting_example.htm) and you're away. I would *never* personally attempt to write a reporting suite myself in Salesforce.. when one already exists. Creating a field = 5 minutes work, writing VF+Apex (+Tests) = 2+ days!